# How can I replace specific character from a string in python?

Tags: python, string, replace

First, I tried to replace a couple of 'e' from the string and the string ended up like the following-

```
string = 'Python is e high-level progremming lenguege'
```

**How can I replace those 'e' with spelling errors leaving other 'e' unchanged?**

Comment: In general, to handle this problem, you would need a) a dictionary, to find words which are mispelled, and b) some kind of soundex engine to map incorrectly spelled words to their correct versions.

Comment: Quick solution would be to replace " e " with " a "... Or can try other libraries nltk, textblob to correct spellings...

Answer (score 0):

you could use textblob.

```
from textblob import TextBlob

text = "Python is e high-level progremming lenguege"   # incorrect spelling
correct_text = TextBlob(text).correct()
print(correct_text)

>>> Python is e high-level programming language
```

Note: 'e' is not changed as 'a' because it corrects only spelling not letters or grammers.